Laravel Query db table against date value this value may come from json meta->date or may depend on created at
I have some table called services which i store service records. i have a situation where i can add those services from 2 different places [ Reservation , POS ].
table structure for services table is like the following
id,number,....,meta [ json column ].
with each service added i store meta information in the json but here is my problem the services added from reservation meta is inserted like this without date value in json
{"qty": 1, "category": "service", "services": [{"id": 2503, "qty": 1, "ttx": 0, "vat": 0, "price": "10", "category": "service", "statement": "beans", "sub_total": 10, "ttxIsChecked": false, "vatIsChecked": false, "totalGeneralSum": 10}], "statement": "beans", "sub_total": 10, "ttx_total": "0.00", "vat_total": "0.00", "payment_type": null, "total_with_taxes": "10.00"}

services added from pos meta is inserted like this with date value in json
{"pos": true, "qty": 1, "date": "2024-04-20 13:02", "from": "alex", "note": "1 × beans ,", "type": 107272, "address": null, "category": "service-deposit", "employee": "Mr man", "services": [{"id": 2503, "qty": 1, "ttx": 0, "vat": "1.50", "price": "10.00", "category": "service", "statement": "beans", "sub_total": 10, "ttxIsChecked": false, "vatIsChecked": true, "totalGeneralSum": 11.5}], "pay_later": true, "reference": null, "statement": "beans", "sub_total": "10.00", "ttx_total": "0.00", "vat_total": "1.50", "tax_number": null, "payment_type": null, "customer_name": null, "total_with_taxes": "11.50"}

So i need to say here query let your first priority to search with the date value of the json but if there is no date value in the json please search with the created at column of the record.
What i have tried so far.
 $from = Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d H:i');
        return $query->where('meta->date', '>=', $from)
                ->orWhere('created_at', '>=', $from);

I've also tried this
 $from = Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d H:i');
        return $query->where(function($query) use ($from) {
            $query->whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(meta, 'one', '\$.date')");
            if($query->exists()){
                $query->where('meta->date', '>=', $from);
            }else{
                $query->Where('created_at', '>=', $from);
            }
        });

Both ways are wrong and dropping some records. so what am missing guys.
I also though of sticking with one way that all records should have date value in the json and this will work but i have to edit over 113k records to copy created at value then get the meta of the record then update the meta and insert new date json value

You might not like what I am going to say, but updating this so that every JSON has a date value, instead of patching this up with a band-aid now will definitely help you in the long run..

i bid you are right , but what you think shall i make new column for indexing purposes or stick with json

A new column? For date? I mean why not, I don't see how the whole JSON could not be restructured into actual relationships which would make it heaps easier to work with if done correctly. Of course you would have some issues regarding backwards compatibility, but you could attempt migrating the JSON to the new relationships then or keep this active and switch users to the new setup.
